# Function being called but is not doing anything

Tags: c, search, data-structures, error-handling, linked-list

I am creating a student management system in C using linked list. I have created a function called `search` which has takes input from user from one of four options and then performs search operation on the student list.

```
struct Program { //structure to hold information of program
    char p_name[50];    //name of program
    char p_code[10];    //code of program
    char responsible[50];   //person responsible for program
    char r_email[50];   //email of responsible
    struct Program *next;
};

struct Student {    //structure to hold information of student
    int personal_no;
    char name[50];
    char gender[6];
    struct Program *study_program;
    int age;
    char email[50];
    struct Student *next;
};
```

The code is not optimized and I will work on making in better but here is the function:

```
void studyProgram(struct Student *head) {
    struct Student *t = NULL;
    struct Program *temp = programs;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        int count = 0;
        int male = 0;
        int female = 0;
        float age = 0;
        printf("Program: %s\n", temp->p_name);
        t = head;
        while (t != NULL) {
            if (!strcmp(temp->p_code, t->study_program->p_code)) {
                count++;
                age += t->age;
                if (!strcmp(_strupr(t->gender), "MALE")) {
                    male++;
                } else {
                    female++;
                }
            }
            t = t->next;
        }
        age = age / count;
        printf("Number of Students: %d\n", count);
        printf("Number of Males: %d\n", male);
        printf("Number of Females: %d\n", female);
        printf("Average age: %f\n", age);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void search(struct Student *head) {
    int p;
    struct Student *temp = head;
    int ch;
    printf("What do you want to search for:\n");
    printf("1.Personal Number\n2.Name\n3.Study Program\n4.Statistics\nOption: ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    if (ch == 1) {
        printf("Enter personal number:\n");
        scanf("%n", &p);
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (temp->personal_no == p) {
                display(temp);
                return;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    else if (ch == 2) {
        char n[50];
        printf("Enter name:\n");
        scanf("%s", n);
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (!strcmp(temp->name, n)) {
                display(temp);
                return;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    else if (ch == 3) {
        char n[10];
        printf("Enter program code:\n");
        scanf("%s", n);
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (!strcmp(temp->study_program->p_code, n)) {
                display(temp);
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    else if (ch == 4) {
        int count = 0;
        int male = 0;
        int female = 0;
        float age = 0;
        
        while (temp != NULL) {
            count++;
            age += temp->age;
            if (!strcmp(strupr(temp->gender), "MALE")) {
                male++;
            } else {
                female++;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        age = age / count;
        printf("Number of Students: %d\n", count);
        printf("Number of Males: %d\n", male);
        printf("Number of Females: %d\n", female);
        printf("Average age: %f\n", age);
        studyProgram(head);
    }
}

void display(struct Student *head) {
    struct Student *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("Peronsal No: %d\n", temp->personal_no);
        printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);
        printf("Gender %s\n", temp->gender);
        printf("Study Program: %n\n", temp->study_program->p_name);
        printf("Age: %d\n", temp->age);
        printf("Email: %s\n", temp->email);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Option `1`-`3` perform basic search operation which are self explanatory. Option `4` provides information about, firstly, the total no of players, no of males and females and then their average age. The `studyProgram` function is then called which calculates the same attributes for each study program.

`programs` is a global variable structure that contains all the information of the programs (CS, AI).

I have been stuck on this for a long time and cannot figure out a solution.
The `studyProgram` function is not working at all. The display function is not displaying any information. In case `1`, for personal number the input is skipped when the option is selected.

Can anybody point out where I am making a mistake(s)?

programs is a global variable that contains all the information of the programs (CS, AI).

**Edit:**

Code for creating the linked list:

```
struct Student *add(struct Student *head) {
    struct Student *student = (struct Student *)malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    student = inputStudent(); //function to take input from user about student fields
    student->next = NULL;
    
    if (head == NULL) {
        /* if head is NULL, set student as the new head */
        head = student;
    } else {
        /* if list is not empty, insert student in beginning of head */
        student->next = head;
        head = student;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Not reading all of your code, your usage of `scanf()` (for example, `scanf("%d", ch);`) is wrong. `%d` needs *a pointer to* `int` variable.

Comment: You haven't provided a minimal reproducible example. What is `programs`? Is it a global variable? Please don't make us guess.

Comment: The calls to `display()` in your `search()` function seem to assume that it will display *one* `Student`, but instead, `display()` attempts to display a whole (sub)list of them.

Comment: You say that the `display()` function is not displaying any information.  Are you sure it is being called at all?  If it is called but does not attempt to write anything to the standard output, then that would be because its argument is a null pointer.

Comment: I am inclined to guess that the main issue(s) you are struggling with at the moment are in some of the code you did not present.  I am particularly suspicious of the code that is responsible for constructing your linked lists, but I can only guess about code I can't see.  This is where we ask for a [mre] demonstrating the problem.  And note well that "minimal reproducible example" does not mean a full dump of your whole program.  Follow the link if you need an explanation of what it *does* mean.

Comment: Also, this would be a good time to learn to use a debugger.  If you are using an IDE to develop your code then it probably has an integrated one.  If you're not using an IDE or you don't like its integrated debugger, then there are command-line alternatives, such as `gdb`.

Comment: Did you notice that `add()` is doing the same thing whether head is NULL or not?  And what after head has changed, do you save the return value of that function?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues:

- `char gender[6];` is too short to contain the string `female`.
- `printf("Study Program: %n\n", temp->study_program->p_name);` instead of %n, you should use `%s`
- `scanf("%n", &p);`  you should use `%d` to convert an `int` value.
- `scanf("%s", n);` is risky: to avoid buffer overflows, you should use `%49s` for `ch == 2` and `%9s` for `ch == 3`
- function `add` allocates memory for a `Student` structure but the pointer gets immediately overwritten by the result of `inputStudent`, which you did not provide. The memory is lost. Note also that inserting at the beginning of the list does not require special casing the empty string.  Here is a simplified version:

  ```
  struct Student *add(struct Student *head) {
      struct Student *student = inputStudent();
      student->next = head;
      return student;
  }
  ```
- the function `display` outputs the full list of students and their details.  If you do not get any output, the list must be empty or the head of the list must have been set to `NULL` in an unexpected way.
- for case `ch == 1`, the input does not store the number into `p` (because of the `%n` instead of `%d`), which would explain why no student is never found.  Function `display()` seems to be expected to output a single student, but your implementation outputs the full list.